# Solving $x + \frac1x < \frac12 (7-x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Solve $x + \frac1x < \frac12 (7-x)$.

$x + \frac1x < \frac12 (7-x)$  becomes $3x^2 -7x + 2 <0$
I noticed that $x<0$ good for $x + \frac1x < \frac12 (7-x)$  but not for $3x^2 -7x + 2 <0$
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have multiplies both sides of $$x + \frac1x < \frac12 (7-x)$$ by the common denominator of  $2x$

Notice that if $2x>0$ you do not change the orientation but if $2x<0$ you have to change the direction of inequality.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply an inequality by a negative number the inequality sign is reversed.

You are multiplying by $x$ so you have reverse the inequality sign when $x <0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you multiply by $x$ both sides of the inequality, you have to check the sign of $x$! 
In fact the inequality $A<B$ is equivalent to $Ax<Bx$ for $x>0$, and  it is equivalent to $Ax>Bx$ for $x<0$.

In your case we have:

1) $x + \frac1x < \frac12 (7-x)$  becomes $3x^2 -7x + 2 <0$ for $x>0$

2) $x + \frac1x < \frac12 (7-x)$  becomes $3x^2 -7x + 2 >0$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

We can’t multiply by $x$ since we are not sure that $x>0$.

We can proceed considering two cases $x>0$ and $x<0$. In the second case the sign of the inequality needs to be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly true that for $x>0$ we have

$$x + \frac1x < \frac12 (7-x) \underset{\text{mult. by $2x$}}{\implies} 2x^2+2<7x-x^2 \implies 3x^2-7x+2 < 0$$

but we cannot make the same steps for $x<0$. If $x<0$ then multiplying by $x$ flips the sign of the inequality so that

$$x + \frac1x < \frac12 (7-x) \underset{\text{mult. by $2x$}}{\implies} 2x^2+2>7x-x^2 \implies 3x^2-7x+2 > 0$$